# How to avoid sql insert duplicates using uploadify for multiple image upload

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

I am trying to upload multiple jpgs using uploadifive/uploadify.
In my uploadify.php file I am:

1) Running a query to check the current photoid and incrementing by one to assign new photo id:

```
        $qry="SELECT * FROM tblphotos ORDER BY photoid DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row['photoid'] == '')
        {
            $photoid = 1;
        }
        else{
            $photoid = $row['photoid'] + 1;
        }
```

2) Running a query to check current sort order (sort id) of photo and assigning new sort id based on previous entry:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM tblphotos WHERE elementid = $workid 
and phototype ='work' ORDER BY sortorder DESC LIMIT 1;";

        $result=mysql_query($qry);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $sortorder = $row['sortorder'];
        if($row['sortorder'] == '')
        {
            $sortorder = 1;
        }
        else{
            $sortorder = $row['sortorder'] + 1;
        }
```

3) Finally, after getting the new photo id and sort id, I am making the sql insert for the photo info to be stored in the database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblphotos (photoid, elementid, photoname, sortorder, phototype) 
VALUES ($photoid, $workid, '$new_file_name', $sortorder, 'work');");
```

**My problem is that in the database the photoid and sortid are being duplicated randomly for some photos/images.** There should be one insert for one image. It is as if uploadify is launching two queries/inserts at once as it uploads multiple photos and thus duplicating the sql insert. Please help. (I haven't used the autoincrement for id's in the database because I am using multiple 'types' of photos.)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates you could use `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT`